# Download SSL Image in PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, openssl

I want to download the image in PHP using curl. but it is not working. When I run the code, it takes about 1 minute and goes to timeout with the blank downloaded image file.

it seems like cURL is not able to resolve SSL transfer.

I tried many online solutions. But not any solve my problem. Please help me

Here is my code: (Method 1)

```
$http_img = 'https://www.adidas.ca/dis/dw/image/v2/aaqx_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-adidas-CA-Site/Sites-adidas-products/en_CA/v1545380233904/zoom/DV2807_00_plp_laydown.jpg?sw=440&sfrm=jpg';
$dest_image = fopen('dest_image.jpg', 'wb');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $http_img);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $dest_image);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:/wamp/www/test/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Here is my code: (Method 2)

```
$http_img = 'https://www.adidas.ca/dis/dw/image/v2/aaqx_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-adidas-CA-Site/Sites-adidas-products/en_CA/v1545380233904/zoom/DV2807_00_plp_laydown.jpg?sw=440&sfrm=jpg';
$dest_image = fopen('dest_image.jpg', 'wb');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $http_img);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $dest_image);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
```

I read somewhere that old curl or OpenSSL does not support TLS 1.2. But it is not in mine case. Here are PHP cURL version Details:

```
array (size=9)
  'version_number' => int 473856
  'age' => int 4
  'features' => int 2428829
  'ssl_version_number' => int 0
  'version' => string '7.59.0' (length=6)
  'host' => string 'x86_64-pc-win32' (length=15)
  'ssl_version' => string 'OpenSSL/1.1.0i' (length=14)
  'libz_version' => string '1.2.11' (length=6)
  'protocols' => 
    array (size=21)
      0 => string 'dict' (length=4)
      1 => string 'file' (length=4)
      2 => string 'ftp' (length=3)
      3 => string 'ftps' (length=4)
      4 => string 'gopher' (length=6)
      5 => string 'http' (length=4)
      6 => string 'https' (length=5)
      7 => string 'imap' (length=4)
      8 => string 'imaps' (length=5)
      9 => string 'ldap' (length=4)
      10 => string 'pop3' (length=4)
      11 => string 'pop3s' (length=5)
      12 => string 'rtsp' (length=4)
      13 => string 'scp' (length=3)
      14 => string 'sftp' (length=4)
      15 => string 'smb' (length=3)
      16 => string 'smbs' (length=4)
      17 => string 'smtp' (length=4)
      18 => string 'smtps' (length=5)
      19 => string 'telnet' (length=6)
      20 => string 'tftp' (length=4)
```

You can also suggest a solution other than cURL to download SSL image

**[EDIT]**

Error log for (Method 2)

```
*   Trying 104.117.73.200...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.adidas.ca (104.117.73.200) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* ignoring certificate verify locations due to disabled peer verification
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=DE; ST=Bavaria; L=Herzogenaurach; O=adidas AG; OU=Global IT; CN=www.global.adidas.com
*  start date: Jul 19 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 18 12:00:00 2019 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /dis/dw/image/v2/aaqx_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-adidas-CA-Site/Sites-adidas-products/en_CA/v1545380233904/zoom/DV2807_00_plp_laydown.jpg?sw=440&sfrm=jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: www.adidas.ca
Accept: */*

* OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the stderr log. ```$errh=tmpfile();curl_setopt_array($ch,[CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$errh]);curl_exec($ch);rewind($errh);$err=stream_get_contents($errh);fclose($errh);var_dump($err);```

Comment: @hanshenrik I have added log for method 2 code. Method 1 code loading continuously until I click on a close button in browser

Comment: it's almost certainly a old-and-fixed-bug in your old outdated libopenssl (which is from 2016) - just update your openssl lib to a recent 2018 version (which, unless you're compiling libcurl & php yourself, means you need to update php), and the error should go away.

Comment: @hanshenrik I have upgraded PHP version to 7.2.10. But still not working. Now error has changed, See error log. Thank you for help

Comment: php 7.2.10 with which version of openssl?

Comment: now it seems to get `WSAECONNRESET (10054) Connection reset by peer. `, which OS is PHP running on?

Comment: @hanshenrik it is OpenSSL/1.1.0i and window 8.1

Comment: is any firewall installed on the windows 8.1 system?

Comment: @hanshenrik Yes firewall was on, so i have disabled it. But still the same issue. Actually, the issue is only with https://www.adidas.ca/ website images. I can download an SSL image of other websites. But Adidas images can be open in a web browser